# Murmurhash2 Unsigned Int overflow

Tags: c, murmurhash

I'm currently trying to implement a hashtable/trie, but when I pass in parameters to murmurhash2, it gives back a number but I get run time errors of unsigned int overflow:

test.c:53:12: runtime error: unsigned integer overflow: 24930 * 1540483477 cannot be represented in type 'unsigned int'

test.c:60:4: runtime error: unsigned integer overflow: 2950274797 * 1540483477 cannot be represented in type 'unsigned int'
6265

I've put a bunch of stars(*) on the lines 53 and 60

I'm not sure if I'm passing some parameters wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned int MurmurHash2 ( const void * key, int len, unsigned int seed );

int main(void)
{
   const char* s= "aa";
   unsigned int number= MurmurHash2 (s, (int)strlen(s), 1) % 10000;
   printf("%u\n", number);
}

unsigned int MurmurHash2 ( const void * key, int len, unsigned int seed )
{
// 'm' and 'r' are mixing constants generated offline.
// They're not really 'magic', they just happen to work well.

const unsigned int m = 0x5bd1e995;
const int r = 24;

// Initialize the hash to a 'random' value

unsigned int h = seed ^ len;

// Mix 4 bytes at a time into the hash

const unsigned char * data = (const unsigned char *)key;

while(len >= 4)
{
    unsigned int k = *(unsigned int *)data;

    k *= m;
    k ^= k >> r;
    k *= m;

    h *= m;
    h ^= k;

    data += 4;
    len -= 4;
}

// Handle the last few bytes of the input array

switch(len)
{
case 3: h ^= data[2] << 16;
case 2: h ^= data[1] << 8;
case 1: h ^= data[0];
        h *= m; ************************************************
};

// Do a few final mixes of the hash to ensure the last few
// bytes are well-incorporated.

h ^= h >> 13;
h *= m;   **************************************
h ^= h >> 15;

return h;
}
```

Comment: Are you building your program with a sanitizer like `-fsanitize=integer`?

Comment: the stars (`*`) are a great idea for marking the lines... but maybe use `// **** line 53` (for example) so they are a valid C comment...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you're building with the UBSan option `-fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow` or some other option like `-fsanitize=integer` that enables this check. [The documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) says:

> Note that unlike signed integer overflow, unsigned integer is not undefined behavior. However, while it has well-defined semantics, it is often unintentional, so UBSan offers to catch it.

In the case of MurmurHash, unsigned integer overflow in multiplications is fully intentional, so you should disable the option.

- If you use `-fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow` explicitly, remove it.
- If it is enabled by another option, pass `-fno-sanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow`.
- Alternatively, annotate the function `MurmurHash2` with `__attribute__((no_sanitize("unsigned-integer-overflow")))`.

Another note: Your code seems to be copied from the [32-bit reference implementation of MurmurHash2](https://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/) which assumes 32-bit `int`s. You should consider using `uint32_t` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned int` has a system dependent number of bits.

On most systems, this number is 32 bits (4 bytes) but some systems might use different sizes (i.e. 64bits (8 bytes) on some machines).

However, murmur hash "words" are a specific size. The 64 bit variant requires a 64bit unsigned type and the 32 bit variant requires a 32bit unsigned type.

This inconsistency can be resolved by using the `uint64_t` or `uint32_t` types defined in `<stdint.h>`.

I would add that the suffix `UL` (unsigned long) should probably be added to any numerical constants you use. i.e. `2950274797UL * 1540483477UL`.

As indicated by @nwellnhof, your code seems to use the 32 bit variant of the algorithm.

The overflow in the multiply instruction is normal in these cases (where the result larger than the number of available bits and is truncated). This loss of data is acceptable as part of the hashing process.

Consider informing the compiler about the expected result using:

```
 h = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)h * m) & 0xFFFFFFFF)
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Given the 32-bit constant `0x5bd1e995`, the OP wants to implement the 32-bit variant. The code seems to be copied from the [reference implementation](https://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/) which uses `unsigned int`s.

Comment: @nwellnhof - I hadn't noticed, thanks. I updated the answer to reflect this observation.

Comment: An `unsigned int` type with 8 bits would not conform to the C specification. It needs at least 16 bits.

Comment: @IanAbbott - oops... I meant 8 bytes (64 bits). Some machines interfaces use the larger `int` in 128 bit instruction chips. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: Thanks! Line 60 still erred so I used h*=m%2^32 to get it back in range.

Comment: @JeffGuan - I'm happy to help. as to the "h*=m%2^32", I might point out @nwellnhof 's answer regarding compiler flags. The unsigned overflow in the multiplication is expected and should be ignored rather than fixed. As to a fix, I would recommend `h = (uint32_t)( (h*m) & 0xFFFFFFFF)` instead of a modulus operation. (I updated the answer with this tip).